# error: junk `bswapl eax movl %eax' after register

Tags: gcc, assembly, macros, gnu-assembler

I define a MACRO in GAS source code. But it is not compiled by gcc.

The following is my defined MACRO.

```
#define MSGSCHEDULE0(index) \
    movl (index*4)(%rsi)    ,%eax \
    bswapl eax \
    movl %eax   ,(index*4-272)(%rdi)
```

The below is  Assembler messages:

> error: junk `bswapl eax movl %eax' after register

I want to use this MACRO in my code as following:

```
MSGSCHEDULE0(0)
MSGSCHEDULE0(1)
MSGSCHEDULE0(2)
//...
MSGSCHEDULE0(16)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a semicolon to signal GAS the end of line:

```
#define MSGSCHEDULE0(index) \
    movl (index*4)(%rsi),%eax; \
    bswapl %eax; \
    movl %eax,(index*4-272)(%rdi)
```

Don't forget the percentage sign for registers.

Comment: Thanks, I am newer for gas.